# Postgres default superuser doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

so I've been trying to enter my Postgres database in a Docker image by going to the image's shell and typing `psql -U postgres` but it returns an error `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`. It used to work, and out of nowhere it stopped working...
I'm free to provide the docker-compose file if it helps you better understand the problem.

What could I have done wrong?

Thanks alot for your time.

**Edit 1: docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
    app:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        networks:
            - app-net
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy
    db:
        image: "postgres:14"
        hostname: "postgres"
        user: "postgres"
        container_name: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: dei_acolhimento_v1
            POSTGRES_USER: dei_acolhimento_root
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 6h7jf8kg3d
            PGPASSWORD: 6h7jf8kg3d
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 5
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./init-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sh
        networks:
            - app-net
volumes:
    pgdata:
networks:
    app-net:
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `podman run --detach --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password --name postgres --rm docker.io/postgres:15.3-alpine3.18@sha256:8aa5154e724b1d5c23d3df387a65e975d67253292d224ffdc22d125c0d6d4bda; sleep 1; podman exec -it postgres psql -U postgres; podman stop postgres` works fine for me.

Comment: Please provide the docker-compose file you are using.

Comment: The user probably has a different name. If in doubt, start PostgreSQL in single-user mode and `SELECT rolname FROM pg_authid WHERE oid = 10`.

Comment: @SebDieBln I just editted the question

Comment: It uses a different default user because you told it to, that is what POSTGRES_USER does.  The real question would be, why did it used to work?

Answer (score 1):

Your setup sets the `POSTGRES_USER` environment variable and therefore does not use the default `postgres` user but in your case `dei_acolhimento_root`. See [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) for extending/modifying the Postgres docker container.

Note that the name of the database again differs from the name of the user because `POSTGRES_DB` is set to `dei_acolhimento_v1`.